# Seeking a correct relationship between the number of zeros of an entire function and it's derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

As far as polynomials are concerned, we know by virtue of fundamental theorem of algebra that a polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and its derivative then will have $n-1$ roots.  Thus we can say that the number of roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ is greater than the number of roots of its derivative.

However, my concern is that can I get similar conclusion  for transcendental entire functions ?

Note that for the entire function $e^z$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Little remark : "it's" isn't the same as "its"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That conclusion does not hold for transcendental entire functions. As an example, if $h$ is an entire function then $f(z) = e^{h(z)}$ has no zeros, but $f'(z) = h'(z)e^{h(z)}$ can have finitely many (take $h$ as a polynomial) or infinitely many  (e.g. $h(z) = \sin(z)$) zeros.

There is also no general estimate in the other direction: $g(z) = 1 + e^z$ has infinitely many zeros, but $g'(z) = e^z$ has none.

Comment: From this counter example, can I conclude that the number of zeros ( if they exist ) of derivative of a transcendental enitre function is greater than or equal to that of itself ?

Comment: @Nik: No. $g(z) = 1+(z-1)e^z$ has infinitely many zeros, but $g'(z) = ze^z$ only one.

Comment: Then am I right to say that no relation can be drawn between number of zeros of a transcendental entire function and its derivative ?

Comment: @Nik: That's what the examples demonstrate. – There are some results in special cases. E.g. if $f$ is an entire function of finite non-integral order then both $f$ and $f'$ have infinitely many zeros, and $N(r, 0, f)$ and $N(r, 0, f')$ have the same order of growth. But that goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Nik: Does this answer your question now? Let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: Yes sir, it's clear now. Also, you have mentioned that if order of $f$ is finite non-integral, then $N(r, 0, f)$ and $N(r, 0, f')$ have same order of growth. Since I am a beginner in Nevanlinna theory, I would like to see how and why this phenomenon happen, although it is beyond the scope of this question.